# Database connection to a particular instance

Tags: weblogic, datasource

We have two oracle database instances say instance1 and instance2. We are creating a datasource in weblogic to instance1. 
Problem is that when I create a connection with my datasource in my application sometimes it gives me me connection to 'instance2' also. How can I avoid that situation to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven an Oracle RAC of 2 nodes configured. If you want all of your instances to be pegged to one of the DB nodes, you will want to modify the DB connection string so that you're not using the HA RAC connect string, but rather the connect string for a single instance.

Unless you have multipools configured, the load balancing between database instances is relayed over to the DB driver and the DB URL configured within the datasources. I doubt this has to do with the driver version WebLogic is using but it's always a good idea to match the jars with the point release of the DB.

I do not recommend moving away from the cluster connect string to a single instance - If the setup is meant to be active/passive, have a chat with your DBA and modify the connect string so that you still have a failover defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the AlgorithmType from "Load-Balancing" to AlgorithmType="Failover"
Or ensure that DB connect string is pointing to just one of the DB instances. you seem to be currently connecting to the DNS of your DB or providing multiple ip.

Comment: I am not making a multi data source. Also I am making my datasource to point to only instance. In my connect string of Datasource, only Instance name is mentioned. I am not able to understand why it is connecting me to another instance.